Cannot read property 'makeMutable' of undefined
I installed "react-native-reanimated ^3.11.0"
here is bable.config.js after adding plugins:
according to reanimated docs
module.exports = {
  presets: ['module:@react-native/babel-preset'],
  plugins: ['react-native-reanimated/plugin'],
};

App giving an error as
Cannot read property 'makeMutable' of undefine
React Native version
0.74.1
Device
Android Emulator
I am sharing screenshot of error
I installed latest version of react-native-reanimated 3.11.0
and also add plugins in bable.config.js
Here is bable code:
module.exports = {
  presets: ['module:@react-native/babel-preset'],
  plugins: ['react-native-reanimated/plugin'],
};


do all things according to reanimated docs

About 10 days ago, I was using "react-native-reanimated": "^3.9.0" without any issues. However, after upgrading to version 3.11.0, I started encountering the same problem. I resolved the issue by downgrading the version and running
first
npm install react-native-reanimated@3.9.0
after
npm start -- --reset-cache.

I resolver issue by installing latest version of react-native-gesture-handler@2.16.2 by
yarn add react-native-gesture-handler
These both maybe interconnected with each other.
After installing library reset cache by
npm start --reset-cache
It worked for me

https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-reanimated/issues/5625#issuecomment-1926979262
Check this link
open android/build.gradle
change ndk version to 23.1.7779620
here is the example:
ext {
    buildToolsVersion = "34.0.0"
    minSdkVersion = 21
    compileSdkVersion = 34
    targetSdkVersion = 34
    ndkVersion = "23.1.7779620" //"25.1.8937393"
    kotlinVersion = "1.8.0"
    supportLibVersion = "28.0.0"
}


Don't forget todo yarn start --reset-cache
Check this link for RN reanimated
https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-reanimated/docs/fundamentals/getting-started/
Also, step 3 should be ignored based on this link
https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-reanimated/issues/6507

I am using
"react-native-reanimated": "^3.16.6",
"react-native": "0.76.3"

I have added plugins: ['react-native-reanimated/plugin'] in babel.config.js just like you did.
module.exports = {
  presets: ['module:@react-native/babel-preset'],
  plugins: ['react-native-reanimated/plugin'],
};

Add the key part is resetCache:true in metro.config.js like:
const {getDefaultConfig, mergeConfig} = require('@react-native/metro-config');
const { wrapWithReanimatedMetroConfig } = require('react-native-reanimated/metro-config');

/**
 * Metro configuration
 * https://reactnative.dev/docs/metro
 *
 * @type {import('metro-config').MetroConfig}
 */
const config = {
  resetCache: true,
};

module.exports = wrapWithReanimatedMetroConfig(
  mergeConfig(getDefaultConfig(__dirname), config)
);

